# Retrieve Json data - how?

Tags: json, swift, url

How do I get the value of Matches Played and Score? I don't know how to retrieve the Json data with this structure.

```
lifeTimeStats =     (
        {
            key = "Matches Played";
            value = 764;
        },
        {
             key = Score;
             value = "126,830";
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try , I expect you have the data of that json

```
do {

     var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]

     if let current = json["lifeTimeStats"] as? [Any] {
        if let Key_value = current[0] as? [String : Any] {
           if let Score_String = Key_value["key"] as? String {
             self.Score.text = Score_String
           }
        }
      }  
   }
 catch let err as NSError {
    print(err)
  }
```

Comment: I assume that the data the OP posted is JSON data. So the first step would be to convert the JSON to native objects, presumably using `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying so fast! The Score_String is now equal to the key. I want to have the value of the key = Score and key = "Matches Played"!

Comment: you have the data of the json ?? how you get it ?

Comment: where is json data , are this array of Dictionary